# Google Cloud Compute Engine instance built from template doesn't change region

Tags: google-compute-engine

I just have created an image on Computer Engine from my template, setting the instance region to “us-west-1 (Oregon)” -> "us-west-1b”.
The region is one of the available for GPU/K80 based on this:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/

However I get an error:

The resource 'projects/xxxx-yyyy-nnnnnn/zones/us-east1-b/acceleratorTypes/nvidia-tesla-k80' was not found

The strange thing is the “us-east1-b” as I selected “us-west-1b” (same error if I choose europe or asia).

I have already quotas for that (all regions GPU and K80).

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Have you created your instance using the `gcloud` command? This is what I did to create first the template and then the instance based on it, using `glcoud`.

This is the full command I used:

```
gcloud compute instance-templates create [my-template-name] --machine-type n1-standard-4 --image-family debian-9 --accelerator type=nvidia-tesla-k80,count=4 --maintenance-policy TERMINATE --restart-on-failure --image-project debian-cloud --boot-disk-size 250GB
```

The template was successfully created, so I proceeded to create my instance based on that template:

```
gcloud compute instances create [my-instance-name] --source-instance-template [my-template-name]
```

Now, I was prompted this message:

> Did you mean zone [europe-west1-c] for instance:
>   [my-instance-name] (Y/n)?

Responding yes gives me the error you got, but responding no and picking the zone you mentioned, `us-west1-b` successfully created the instance.

Here you have a couple of links on how to [create instance templates](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates) and how to [create an instance from an instance template](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-vm-from-instance-template).

Note that in the example, the template is not created with an accelerator. You can do that as done in the first snippet.